# CSS selector check attribute inside string

Tags: jquery, css

I am looking for a css selector check if a given attribute is inside a value.

For instance:
I have a `<a class="myClass" href="Administration/Menus"></a>` and a value: `Administration/Menus/Create`

My goal is to select all elements where value contains the content of href.

I tried doing the following `$('.myClass [href*="' + value + '"]')`

But this doesnt work since my href doesnt contain value, instead value contains href...

Comment: It would be `$('.myClass[href*="' + value + '"]')` as there's only one element and space indicates child

Comment: Can you give an example of how you find what to look for and where it would match.   "value contains the href" and "href doesn't contain value, value contains href" doesn't make much sense without some context.

Comment: I get value from window.location.pathname
So if my url is in "Administration/Menus/Create" i want to select the link whose href contains "Administration/Menus".

Comment: Would you also expect to select a menu that is just `href="Administration"`?  Or is it always just removing the last part of the path?

Comment: Only removing the last part. If not yeah I would get situations where I would get administration, or even just "A".

Comment: yes a .filter solution might work

Comment: window.location.pathname.split('/');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.filter` to check each if each entry matches the input.

> Example input: `Administration/Menus/Create`
>
> Find where href is `Administration/Menus`
>
> "Only removing the last part"

Use `.split`, `.slice` and `.join` to remove the last part:

```
var lookfor = value.split("/").slice(0, -1).join("/")
```

then `.filter` with `.indexOf` to check if the "lookfor" part matches

```js
var value = "Administration/Menus/Create";

var lookfor = value.split("/").slice(0, -1).join("/")
$(".myClass")
  .filter(function() {
    return lookfor.indexOf($(this).attr("href")) >= 0
  })
  .css("color", "pink")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="myClass" href="Administration/Menus">menu</a>
<a class="myClass" href="Administration/Menus/Create">create</a>
<a class="myClass" href="Administration/Menus/Delete">delete</a>
```